# Filtering errors in ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to Show particular errors in validation summary and disappear some errors like below:`  public class LogOnModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username must be entered.")]
    [Display(Name = "Kullanıcı Adı")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password must be entered.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Parola")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

How can I filter particular errors in ValidationSummary() ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you need to suppress certain errors based on logic or are you looking to only ever show specific errors?

Comment: This is related post your issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424003/mvc3-remove-modelstate-errors