# Model Invalidation in Model view viewmodel controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 5. I am trying to make a user-management software. but in the user registration(create) controller my model is getting invalidated. Don't know why. I might have a mistake in my model Binding. Here is the attached code. Any Help is appreciated.

**Model file**

```
public class UserData
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int userid { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Domain ID")]
    [Display(Name = "Domain ID")]
    public string domainid { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose Role")]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string role { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose Country")]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose BU")]
    [Display(Name = "BU")]
    public string bu { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
 + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
            [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
 + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
            [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
 + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Valid Email-ID")]
    [Display(Name = "Email"),DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string email { get; set; }


    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=true)]
    public DateTime date_from { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
    public DateTime date_to { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=true)]
    public bool active { get; set; }

       }
```

**ViewModel File**

```
 public class UserRegistrationViewModel

{

    public UserData userdata { get; set; }

    public string SelectedRole { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }


    public string SelectedCountry { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }


    public string SelectedBU { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BUList { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller file**

```
 public class UserDatasController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDataContext db = new ApplicationDataContext();

    // GET: UserDatas
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.UsersData.ToList());
    }
       public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new UserRegistrationViewModel();
        model.CountryList = from p in XDocument.Load("C:/Users/inkosah/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Policy Assessment/Policy Assessment/country_list.xml").Descendants("Name")
                           //var a=Path.GetFullPath("Policy Asse")
                           let value = (string)p.Element("Text")
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Selected = (value == model.SelectedCountry),
                               Text = (string)p.Element("Text"),
                               Value = value
                           };
        model.BUList = from q in XDocument.Load("C:/Users/inkosah/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Policy Assessment/Policy Assessment/bu_list.xml").Descendants("BU")
                      let value2 = (string)q.Element("BU_Name")
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Selected = (value2 == model.SelectedBU),
                          Text = (string)q.Element("BU_Name"),
                          Value = value2
                      };


        model.RoleList = from n in XDocument.Load("C:/Users/inkosah/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Policy Assessment/Policy Assessment/UserRoleList.xml").Descendants("Role")
                        let value1 = (string)n.Element("Role_Name")
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Selected = (value1 == model.SelectedRole),
                            Text = (string)n.Element("Role_Name"),
                            Value = value1
                        };
        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: UserDatas/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SelectedRole,SelectedCountry,SelectedBU")]UserRegistrationViewModel RegisterData,[Bind(Include="domainid,email")] UserData userdata)
    {
        userdata.date_from = DateTime.Now;
        userdata.date_to = DateTime.MaxValue;
        userdata.active = false;
        userdata.role = RegisterData.SelectedRole;
        userdata.bu = RegisterData.SelectedBU;
        userdata.country = RegisterData.SelectedCountry;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.UsersData.Add(userdata);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(userdata);
    }
```

**create.cshtml**

```
    @model Policy_Assessment.ViewModels.UserRegistrationViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Registration Page";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User Input</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userdata.domainid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userdata.domainid)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userdata.domainid)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userdata.role, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.role)*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRole, Model.RoleList, "-----Role-----")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.SelectedRole)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userdata.country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.country)*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCountry,Model.CountryList,"----Country-----")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userdata.country)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userdata.bu, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedBU,Model.BUList,"--Select BU----")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userdata.bu)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userdata.email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userdata.email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userdata.email)
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userdata.date_from, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userdata.date_from)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userdata.date_from)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userdata.date_to, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userdata.date_to)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userdata.date_to)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userdata.active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userdata.active)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userdata.active)
            </div>
        </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@*<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>*@

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

**Context File**

```
 public class ApplicationDataContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDataContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Policy_Assessment.ViewModels.UserRegistrationViewModel> UserRegistrationData { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Policy_Assessment.Models.UserData> UsersData { get; set; }


}
```

Please Note i am a beginner in MVC ASP.Net. Any Help or Explanation would be helpful.

[image: Breakpoint at userdata object]

[image: Breakpoint at ModelState. Here in the role,country,and for bu i am getting the null value. but in the userdata object the value is showing.]

Comment: What's the validation message?

Comment: i mean to say my model is getting invalidated when doing the (Modelstate.isvalid). even though i am getting my all values inside the create action method.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your create method, once hit, expand the ModelState object and check all object in dictionary to know validation is failing for which property.

Comment: i have done that also. pls take a look at the controller file. before checking ModelState.isvalid I am assigning the values also. but in the modelstate some of the values (role,bu,country) null value is showing. don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Expand the "Errors" collection and read the error.

Comment: @CodeCaster well its null. even though i am setting the value.

Comment: `ModelState` gets filled before your action method is called. Setting properties afterwards won't automagically clear your model errors.

Comment: @CodeCaster can u tell me in which part of my code i am having the error?

Comment: I just explained. The model you get posted is not valid according to your validations. If you want to clear errors for a specific property, see [MVC3 Remove ModelState Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424003/mvc3-remove-modelstate-errors).

Comment: @CodeCaster can u give me some example for binding complex objects ?

Comment: The `role` property of `UserData` is required, but your not binding anything in your view to that property (only to `SelectedRole`) so when it posts back its its null and therefore invalid.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want `selectedRole` value in the role property. How can i get that? i am writing this in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRole, Model.RoleList, "-----Role-----")`. Help would be appreciated as i am new in MVC.

Comment: @user3132179, Personally I would modify the view model to include all the `UserData` properties that you want to edit rather than including `public UserData userdata { get; set; }`, and then map from the view model to the data model in the POST method, but if you want to do it this way, delete property `SelectedRole` and just bind to `userdata.role` as in `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userdata.role, Model.RoleList, ...)` (ditto for other properties)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank u for the advice. can u give me a small example the way you want to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posting back your data model (included as a property of your view model). The data model has a `[Required]` attribute for property `role` but you are creating a control for this property so nothing is bound, meaning its `null` and therefore its invalid. Two ways to solve this.

A. Remove property `string SelectedRole` from the view model and bind directly to the the data model that's included in the view model

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userdata.role, Model.RoleList, ...)
```

Now, `userdata.role` will contain the selected option value and will be valid (note you would need to do this for the other 2 properties as well).

B. Remove property `UserData userdata` from the view model and include in the view model the properties from `UserData` that you are editing

```
public class UserRegistrationViewModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Domain ID")]
  [Display(Name = "Domain ID")]
  public string domainid { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose Role")]
  [Display(Name = "Role")]
  public string role { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose Country")]
  [Display(Name = "Country")]
  public string country { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose BU")]
  [Display(Name = "BU")]
  public string bu { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Email"),DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
  [EmailAddress]
  public string email { get; set; }
  public SelectList RoleList { get; set; }
  public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
  public SelectList BUList { get; set; }
}
```

Note I've excluded properties you don't appear to be editing, used `[EmailAddress]` rather than your Regex (could not see what the regex was doing that an `EmailAddress` attribute is not already doing) and used `SelectList` rather than `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which means you can simplify it to

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new UserRegistrationViewModel();
  var roles = from n in XDocument.Load(....
  model.RoleList = new SelectList(roles, "value", "value");
  ....
  return View(model);
}
```

and then in the POST method, map the properties from the view model to a new instance of the data model, setting the other properties such as `date_from` if required (alternatively you could put these default values in a constructor) and save to the database.

Comment: thanks for the details.. one confusion. why do u have two @Html in the first solution?