# Clear One of Fields Value By ModelState In Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, blazor

I just want one field value to be empty

ModelState.Clear Clear all fields

Model :

```
 public class UserViewModel{
      [Required("")]
      public string Mobile { get; set; }
      [Required("")]
      public string Name { get; set; }
     }
```

Controller :

```
public IActionResult Create(UserViewModel viewModel){
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //clear just field "Name"
 
      return view(viewModel);
    }

  }
```

I want only the "Name" field to be cleaned when I return ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424003/mvc3-remove-modelstate-errors

Comment: @SteveGreene Greene this post for clear errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used ViewBag, it worked better

```
public IActionResult Create(UserViewModel viewModel){
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       ViewBag.value = ""; 
       return view(viewModel);
   }
```

}

Html :

```
<input id="answer" value="@ViewBag.value" asp-for="Name"/>
```

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of a viewmodel and data binding.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 if (ModelState.ContainsKey("Name")) ModelState.Remove("Name");
```

and better to use it this way

```
if (ModelState.ContainsKey("Name")) ModelState.Remove("Name");

if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return view(viewModel);
    }
```

if you want just clear the value

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("Name", new ValueProviderResult(string.Empty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

since you don't clear errors and if it has errors, ModelState still will not be valid.

You can remove errors if you need

```
 ModelState["Name"].Errors.Clear();
```

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy What do you need  remove name for?

Comment: Clear Field Value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ModelState.Remove("FieldName");`